# How to add data in database by clicking a button on client side, but page must not be refreshed

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

The title might be a little confusing.

I'm building a E-commerce web application using Spring Boot. When I click on ***Add to Cart*** on the client side, the page should not be refreshed but the product must be added into the database. I'm using MySQL as my database.

P.S. I'm new to building web apps and sorry if I couldn't explain the problem properly.

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: Use ajax to post the data to a servlet.